# Strange issue with Subversion - Server unexpectedly closed the connection

Tags: svn

I am having a strange issue with Subversion. Its been working all of the time without issue however, I am now trying to import a new project into my subversion repository.

When I do it displays that its added two files, and has transferred 62kb then I get the following error message:

```
SharpSvn.SvnException: Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection.
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, SvnException error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, svn_error_t* error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.RemoteImport(String path, Uri target, SvnImportArgs args, SvnCommitResult& result)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Import(String path, Uri target, SvnImportArgs args, SvnCommitResult& result)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Import(String path, Uri target, SvnImportArgs args)
   at Ankh.Commands.AddToSccCommands.<>c__DisplayClassd.<CheckoutWorkingCopyForSolution>b__a(Object sender, ProgressWorkerArgs a)
   at Ankh.ProgressRunnerService.ProgressRunner.Run(Object arg)
```

I can't see any reason for this.

**UPDATE**

If I add the project but tell the client not to commit the files initially, it is accepted, then when I try and commit the file, it displays that it is adding all the files then when it tries to send the first file I then get the following error:

```
SharpSvn.SvnSystemException: Commit failed (details follow): ---> SharpSvn.SvnSystemException: Error running context: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, SvnException error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, svn_error_t* error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Commit(ICollection`1 paths, SvnCommitArgs args, SvnCommitResult& result)
   at Ankh.Services.PendingChanges.PendingChangeHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1b.<Commit_CommitToRepository>b__19(Object sender, ProgressWorkerArgs e)
   at Ankh.ProgressRunnerService.ProgressRunner.Run(Object arg)
```

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: I don't think I did. I reinstalled a different version (I've got svn, version 1.8.10 currently installed if that helps)

Comment: Ours in 1.6.11 on red hat linux. Everything was working fine. Now its intermittent. Some files I am not able to commit through eclipse /windows while other files I can.

Comment: Yea I was getting exactly the same thing, I think from what I remember something got updated, can't remember if it was client side or server side but it caused some kind of incompatibility so I just reinstalled with the latest release and that resolve the issue

Comment: ok... Thanks! I need to get comfortable with software updates on linux :(

Comment: If you use CentOS maybe this will help. http://snowdream.github.io/blog/centos/2013/11/08/how-to-install-subversion-18-on-centos-64/